# JSON module of Python: Supress exceptions by dictionary access

Tags: python, json

I noticed, if I want to access a key in a JSON document which doesn't exist, there is a sudden exception. 
The problem of this exceptions is, that I wasn't finding in the docu much about it. 
Second problem is, I was not finding function to make checks, whether item is there or not. 
Third thing is, that an exception in this case is not necessary. Returning NULL would be better.
This is some example code. Does someone know an esay approach to either supress throwing an exception or ignore it?

```
def make_command(p):
  type = p['t']

  # remote control is about controlling the model (thrust and attitude)
  if type == 'rc':
    com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['r'], p['p'], p['f'], p['y'])
    send_command("RC#", com)

  # Add a waypoint
  if type == 'uav':
    com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['lat_d'], p['lon_d'], p['alt_m'], p['flag_t'] )
    send_command("UAV#", com)

  # PID config is about to change the sensitivity of the model to changes in attitude
  if type == 'pid':
    com = "%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f" % (
      p['p_rkp'], p['p_rki'], p['p_rkd'], p['p_rimax'],
      p['r_rkp'], p['r_rki'], p['r_rkd'], p['r_rimax'],
      p['y_rkp'], p['y_rki'], p['y_rkd'], p['y_rimax'],
      p['t_rkp'], p['t_rki'], p['t_rkd'], p['t_rimax'],
      p['a_rkp'], p['a_rki'], p['a_rkd'], p['a_rimax'],
      p['p_skp'], p['r_skp'], p['y_skp'], p['t_skp'], p['a_skp'] )
    send_command("PID#", com)

  # This section is about correcting drifts while model is flying (e.g. due to imbalances of the model)
  if type == 'cmp':
    com = "%.2f,%.2f" % (p['r'], p['p'])
    send_command("CMP#", com)

  # With this section you may start the calibration of the gyro again
  if type == 'gyr':
    com = "%d" % (p['cal'])
    send_command("GYR#", com)

  # User interactant for gyrometer calibration
  if type == 'user_interactant':
    ser_write("x")

  # Ping service for calculating the latency of the connection
  if type == 'ping':
    com = '{"t":"pong","v":%d}' % (p['v'])
    udp_write(com, udp_clients)
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so it reads more like an actual question and less like a rant?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but this may help: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Don't add answers to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you parsed a JSON document, it's just a Python data structure. From there on, all normal rules as to how to work with python lists or dictionaries apply. Trying to access a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist will raise a `KeyError`, unless you use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (and possibly provide a default value other that `None`):

```
>>> dct = {'foo': 42}
>>> dct['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bar'
>>>
>>> print dct.get('bar')
None
>>> print dct.get('bar', 'NOTFOUND')
'NOTFOUND'
```

In order to first check if a key is in a dictionary, you simply use the `in` operator (see [docs for `dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)):

```
>>> 'foo' in dct
True
>>> 'bar' in dct
False
```

Comment: Based on my example it would be relatively expensive and much code to check for every key whether there is an exception. Is there a way around?

Comment: Yes, use `dct.get(key, default)` like I demonstrated (with an appropriate default or sentinel value for your use case).